# Error adding Google AdMob on Android libraries - LIBGDX project

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx, admob, google-play-services

I would like to add the Google library to my project libgdx in Android Studio. Currently I have done:

1. opened the SDK manager and downloaded play-services from the SDK manager,
2. added the `compile` string in `build.gradle`:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'`

3. Clicked on `File -> Project Structure -> choose the project` and added the library `play-services 8.4.0`.

When I do the `sync` it gives me this error:

[image]

If I click on `Install and sync repository project` I get an error, this:

[image]

Another test:

```
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
```

If you manually add this library, after all the steps listed... I do not recognize them and it always fails. How do I add? Thank you.

also tried to [Add Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project) to my project, but with unsuccess :(

My goal is to use AdMob banner.

Comment: What's the error you get when you click "install repository and sync project?"

Comment: the error that gives me is that it can not find the sdk , though , I assure you there .

Comment: i have add the error when click on "install repository and sync project"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like at least a few people have had this error before:

[Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240265/failed-to-resolve-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-gcm7-5)

I would try opening the full-on SDK manager (Tools >> Android >> SDK Manager). You can manually download the Google Repository (and any other dependencies) using it.

Comment: Excuse eh..but you read it right the question before answering? as you can well see, use the latest libraries available ... your answer recommends using the latest up to date, which I already use, as I highlighted in the question I asked.